# Codename One:Dont want to show error message on Screen

Tags: codenameone

I have developed application using codename one .I got error "400:Bad Request" thrown by "NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(req)" this method.
I don't want to show that types of errors on screen .What should I do ? 
I have already using "NetworkManager.getInstance().addErrorListener((e) -> e.consume())" but this method couldn't able to stop/consume "400:Bad Request" error to popup on screen. Any other solution for that?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

To prevent that error dialog from showing, you will have to override `handleErrorResponseCode` method in the `ConnectionRequest` or `MultipartRequest` class, depending on which one you are using.

```
ConnectionRequest req = new ConnectionRequest() {

    @Override
    protected void handleErrorResponseCode(int code, String message) {
        if (code == 400) {
            //Do what you want here
        } else {
            Dialog.show("Error", code + ": " + message, "Retry", "Cancel");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are a couple of options such as using the error listener on `NetworkManager` this is listed in the error handling section in the developer guide networking section https://www.codenameone.com/manual/files-storage-networking.html